# Debug an Ionic app published on google play

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I am new to ionic app development. I have managed to make an ionic app and test it using android emulator. It works fine.
My app connects to a backend which is deployed on a DNS server and the data is exchanged. 
This worked fine using ionic serve or even using the command ionic cordova run android --device.
However, the data is not getting updated on backend when I am trying to use the app after installing it from google play.
Can someone please help me how to debug the app.
I have installed the app on my android device and now trying to hit my backend server to update the data.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: you need to test it before publishing. The issue seems to be with whitelisting urls.

Comment: There's no way, after you build your app for release you can't debbug it.